# Hitting Back Button and then Resuming Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, back-button

I am developing a game for Android and have what I imagine to be a very common scenario, but I can't figure out how to do it.

I have a Title Screen where the user can select "New Game".  When they start up a game, I push a GameActivity onto the stack.  Then if the user hits the physical back button the phone, the application goes back to the TitleActivity, as I intend it.  However, I need a way to allow the user to resume the game at this point, but I don't know how to get back to htat instance of the GameActivity.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't guarantee that you will get back to that instance of `GameActivity` you need to save the game state somehow, and make your `GameActivity` able to resume from that saved state.

Make sure you understand the [Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).  The instance of your activity can be killed at any time when it isn't visible, so you need to save state at the proper point ([onSaveInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29)).

Comment: I am handling save state correctly when the Activity is killed.  I really want to know if I can detect if an activity has been killed, because if it has not been killed then I would like to redisplay it without re-initializing everything.  Is this not possible or recommended?

Comment: Take a game like Robo Defense.  You hit "back" while in the game and get to the main menu.  Then you hit "resume game" and you go back to the state you were at.  Do you believe in all cases that the author saves the full state and then reloads it?  Thanks!

Comment: I've spent a great deal of time reading the above links for the purpose of understanding your very question, so i'd advise setting up a couple of test projects to test each step you uncover as you'll keep coming back to them. You might also want to check out http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/testing/index.html as this allows you to test some of the different occasions that you can end up in. such as when your activity is dropped for an incoming call etc. and its on occasions like those that it pays to have tested up front.

Comment: @skaz I see... No, probably not in all cases but you have to assume that can happen any time.  You probably want to use a launch flag on your game activity, like `singleInstance` that causes the existing instance to be used if there is one.  See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#acttask for details.  Also, you probably need to override onBack to prevent it from finishing the activity. Just launch the title screen instead.

Comment: Don't use singleInstance, it has deep meaning for activity task management that you don't want.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  Launching the Title Screen again makes sense, but then if they hit Back again, they would go back to the Game, which I wouldn't want.  I would have to override the default behavior of the back button on all screens, which doesn't feel "natural".  Is this the recommended method?

Comment: The "natural" way is to allow the game activity to finish, and recreate it when the user goes forward to it again.  Anything else will require extra work.  As hackbod pointed out below, if all you have is a title screen and a game screen, you might be better off in one activity.  Generally I don't recommend that for standard applications, but for games it might make sense.

Comment: @hackbod You are right, I think I meant to say singleTask, not singleInstance.

Comment: I would love to save it all out to the database, but I thought that I shouldn't do any "heavy lifting" here.  I would have to save state on about 50 items, which I thought would be too much. I just don't see another way.

Answer (score 1):

The answer I would give is: don't do this.

Finishing an activity (which is what happens by default when you press back) does *finish* that activity.  You don't return to it.

If you want to allow the user to press back to pause your game into a menu, capture the back key with onBackPressed(), and instead of allowing the default behavior of finishing the activity, simply show your menu in-place in that activity.  Generally I think for games making the core game UI be one activity that is the base activity launched for the app makes more sense than trying to split it into activities.  Games are just special that way.